# Unskewing the Data with the PCA's Help

Tags: pca

I'm making some RFM Analyses (Customer Segmentation) and, in order to feed the RFM data to K-Means, I need to unskew the data, as K-Means works best when dealing with symmetrical distributions.

One of the best practices I've found so far is to use `log` transforms in order to unskew the data. However, after a bit of experimenting (and, hopefully, correct intuition), I've also found that PCA is working really well at unskewing the data, without the need of performing a `log` transform. Is this supposed to work or am I in danger of making incorrect assumptions?

On a (*cough*) safer bet, I was planning on using PCA after a `log` transform and the scaling of the data, since it would help to orthogonalize it and, I suppose, improve K-Means's performance. Is this better or worse than simply applying PCA without the `log` transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On a (cough) safer bet, I was planning on using PCA after a log transform and the scaling of the data, since it would help to orthogonalize it and, I suppose, improve K-Means's performance. Is this better or worse than simply applying PCA without the log transform?

This is your solution, this is the normal, most used and best practice on what to do with skewed data

Comment: It does indeed make more sense than the first option, but could you point out a reference?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4408558/#!po=1.36364

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you find that reference? Google? Any others would be more than welcome too. And, for completeness, I would recommend you add them to your answer .

Comment: On a sidenote, there is also a [PowerTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-transformer) function in the `preprocessing` module of sklearn that helps with normalizing distributions.

Comment: Yes! The Box-Cox set of transformations is a generalization of the log transformation with $\lambda = 0$